# Python equivalent of Perl's HTTP::Async->next_response

Tags: python, perl, http, asynchronous, python-3.x

I'm looking for a way to do the equivalent of Perl's HTTP::Async module's next_response method

The HTTP::Async module doesn't spawn any background threads, nor does it use any callbacks. Instead, every time anyone (in my case, the main thread) calls next_response on the  object, all the data that has been received by the OS so far is read (blocking, but instantaneous since it only processes data that's already been received). If this is the end of the response, then next_response returns an HTTP::Response object, otherwise it returns undef.

Usage of this module looks something like (pseudocode):

```
request = HTTP::Async(url)
do:
    response = request->next_response()
    if not response:
        sleep 5 # or process events or whatever
while not response

# Do things with response
```

As far as I can see, Python's urllib or http.client don't support this style. As for why I want to do it in this style:

- This is for an embedded Python environment where I can't spawn threads, nor have Python spawn any.
- I'm restricted to a single thread that is actually the embedding application's thread. This means I cannot have any delayed callbacks either - the application decides when to let my Python code run. All I can do is request the embedding application to invoke a callback of my choosing every 50 milliseconds, say.

Is there a way to do this in Python?

For reference, this is an example of the Perl code I have right now and that I'm looking to port to Python:

```
httpAsync = HTTP::Async->new()

sub httpRequestAsync {
    my ($url, $callback) = @_; # $callback will be called with the response text

    $httpAsync->add(new HTTP::Request(GET => $url));

    # create_timer causes the embedding application to call the supplied callback every 50ms
    application::create_timer(50, sub {
        my $timer_result = application::keep_timer;
        my $response = $httpAsync->next_response;
        if ($response) {
            my $responseText = $response->decoded_content;
            if ($responseText) {
                $callback->($responseText);
            }
            $timer_result = application::remove_timer;
        }

        # Returning application::keep_timer will preserve the timer to be called again.
        # Returning application::remove_timer will remove the timer.
        return $timer_result;
    });
}

httpRequestAsync('http://www.example.com/', sub {
    my $responseText = $_[0];
    application::display($responseText);
});
```

Edit: Given that this is for an embedded Python instance, I'll take all the alternatives I can get (part of the standard library or otherwise) as I'll have to evaluate all of them to make sure they can run under my particular constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you're interested in only retrieving data when YOU call for data to be received, simply add a flag to `handle_receive` and add it to the sleep block inside `handle_receive` thus giving you data only when you call your function.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
import asyncore, errno
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from time import sleep

class sender():
    def __init__(self, sock_send):
        self.s = sock_send
        self.bufferpos = 0
        self.buffer = {}
        self.alive = 1

    def send(self, what):
        self.buffer[len(self.buffer)] = what

    def writable(self):
        return (len(self.buffer) > self.bufferpos)

    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            if self.writable():
                logout = str([self.buffer[self.bufferpos]])
                self.s(self.buffer[self.bufferpos])
                self.bufferpos += 1
            sleep(0.01)

class SOCK(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, _s=None, config=None):
        self.conf = config
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self._s = _s

        self.inbuffer = ''
        #self.buffer = ''
        self.lockedbuffer = False
        self.is_writable = False

        self.autounlockAccounts = {}

        if _s:
            asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, _s)
            self.sender = sender(self.send)

        else:
            asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
            self.create_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            #if self.allow_reuse_address:
            #   self.set_resue_addr()

            self.bind((self.conf['SERVER'], self.conf['PORT']))
            self.listen(5)

            self.sender = None

        self.start()

    def parse(self):
        self.lockedbuffer = True

        ## Parse here
        print self.inbuffer

        self.inbuffer = ''
        self.lockedbuffer = False

    def readable(self):
        return True
    def handle_connect(self):
        pass
    def handle_accept(self):
        (conn_sock, client_address) = self.accept()
        if self.verify_request(conn_sock, client_address):
            self.process_request(conn_sock, client_address)
    def process_request(self, sock, addr):
        x = SOCK(sock, config={'PARSER' : self.conf['PARSER'], 'ADDR' : addr[0], 'NAME' : 'CORE_SUB_SOCK_('+str(addr[0]) + ')'})
    def verify_request(self, conn_sock, client_address):
        return True
    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()
            if self.sender:
                self.sender.alive = False
    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(8192)
        while self.lockedbuffer:
            sleep(0.01)
        self.inbuffer += data
    def writable(self):
        return True
    def handle_write(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
            if not self._s:
            asyncore.loop()

imap = SOCK(config={'SERVER' : '', 'PORT' : 6668})
imap.run()

while 1
    sleep(1)
```

Something along the lines of this?
Asyncore socket that always appends to the inbuffer when there's data to recieve.

You can modify it however you want to, i just pasted a piece of code from another project that happens to be Threaded :)

Last attempt:

```
class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(8192)
        if data:
            self.send(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in the question, the limits of the embedding environment prohibit me from starting new threads.

Comment: It's a "what you can do" answer, mod it, try it out and fiddle around.

Comment: Sorry, I was not talking about your use of the Thread class, but the asyncore.loop() bit. I can't block the thread to wait for asynccore to finish for any significant period of time.

Although I suppose I could fake out the async tasks to return early even when the response isn't complete, and call asyncore.loop() repeately in a timer callback...

Comment: Yepp that can work, to bad you can't use Threads because as i did in my first example i just thew asyncore.loop() into a Thread so it's non-blocking :)

Comment: Is there an easy way to put an HTTP response parser on top of this? I don't want to have to parse the headers and extract the body myself if I can help it (of course it's just a matter of skipping some lines).

Comment: @Arnavion I'd go with BeautifulSoup for parsing HTML tbh.
`soup = BeautifulSoup(self.inbuffer)` and there's a perfect object for fetching and working with the data. Other than that you'd have to build your own if not smi-manually via: http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

Comment: I'm not talking about parsing HTML. Your answer currently returns me the raw string fetched from the TCP socket (i.e., HTTP response headers and body) and I was asking if there was a way to get the body out of that.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work. It seems the call to self.recv(8192) still blocks if the remote server doesn't respond at all.

Comment: I've seen people do `<see my edit>` and that works like a non-blocking operation (not sure how that works and if it even does)